# Replacing whitespace with single tab unless in double quotes

Tags: bash, awk

Assume a multi-line file with strings separated by one or more whitespaces. Assume further that groups of strings can be enclosed by double quotes.

```
> cat file
foo bar "foobar baz qux"
foo "bar foobar baz" qux
"foo   bar foobar" baz   qux   # multiple whitespaces in this line
```

If I wish to replace all whitespaces outside the double quotes with single tab characters using *awk* as listed below, I receive the following:

```
awk '{OFS="\t"; FPAT="([^, ]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"; $1=$1; print}' file
# foo   bar "foobar baz qux" # In this line, strings inside the quote are separated by tabs
# foo   "bar foobar baz"    qux
# "foo  bar foobar" baz qux
```

The problem only seems to be restricted to the line that ends with a double quote.

*EDIT 1:*
To better visualize the issue at hand:

```
awk '{OFS="\t"; FPAT="([^, ]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"; $1=$1; print}' file | cat -A
# foo^Ibar^I"foobar^Ibaz^Iqux"$
# foo^I"bar foobar baz"^Iqux$
# "foo   bar foobar"^Ibaz^Iqux$
```

*EDIT 2:*
It appears that both commands suggested in the answer section work fine unless a certain number or combination of non-letter characters are present in the input. Here is an example:

```
> cat file
foo_bar_baz foo foo_bar . Name=foo;product="bar baz qux"
foo_bar_baz foo foo_bar . Name=foo;product="bar baz qux"
foo_bar_baz foo foo_bar . Name=foo;product="bar baz qux"

> awk -v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^[:blank:]]+' -v OFS='\t' '{$1=$1} 1' file | cat -A
foo_bar_baz^Ifoo^Ifoo_bar^I.^IName=foo;product="bar^Ibaz^Iqux"$
foo_bar_baz^Ifoo^Ifoo_bar^I.^IName=foo;product="bar^Ibaz^Iqux"$
foo_bar_baz^Ifoo^Ifoo_bar^I.^IName=foo;product="bar^Ibaz^Iqux"$

> awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS='\t' FPAT='"[^"]+"|[^ ]+' file | cat -A
foo_bar_baz^Ifoo^Ifoo_bar^I.^IName=foo;product="bar^Ibaz^Iqux"$
foo_bar_baz^Ifoo^Ifoo_bar^I.^IName=foo;product="bar^Ibaz^Iqux"$
foo_bar_baz^Ifoo^Ifoo_bar^I.^IName=foo;product="bar^Ibaz^Iqux"$
```

*EDIT 3:*
This question posed *EDIT 2* is further discussed here: [Replacing whitespace with single tab unless in double quotes - Part II](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34231514/replacing-whitespace-with-single-tab-unless-in-double-quotes-part-ii#34231597)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `gnu-awk` you can do this easily:

```
awk -v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^[:blank:]]+' -v OFS='\t' '{$1=$1} 1' file
foo bar "foobar baz qux"
foo "bar foobar baz"    qux
"foo   bar foobar"  baz qux
```

Comment: Your command works splendid. Still, why does the above example replace whitespaces between double-quotes in the very first line?

Comment: That is because you're setting `FPAT` too late. It should be set from command line as I showed OR in `BEGIN` block to be effective from line #1

Comment: so e.g. `awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"; FPAT="([^ ]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"} {$1=$1} 1' file` should work for you as well.

Comment: Oh, you have already mentioned it in the comments. I will delete my answer then...

Comment: @anubhava After having used your _awk_ command for several days, it appears that it only works in very specific cases. For example, the following file is not processed as expected:                                             `> cat file` `foo_bar_baz foo foo_bar . Name=foo;product="bar baz qux"\nfoo_bar_baz foo foo_bar . Name=foo;product="bar baz qux"\nfoo_bar_baz foo foo_bar . Name=foo;product="bar baz qux"`

Comment: @anubhava A new example has been appended to the question above. Could your code be adjusted so that this new example is processed as expected?

Comment: Sorry just came back online and noted that you already got a good andswer on your new question.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following command:

```
awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS='\t' FPAT='"[^"]+"|[^ ]+'
```

I define two kind of possible field trough the `FPAT` variable:

- a string enclosed in double quotes `"[^"]+"`
- a sequence of non whitespace characters `[^ ]+`

Because the enclosed string comes first, it has a higher precedence.

The results can be better visualized on SO when piping to `cat -A`:

```
awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS='\t' FPAT='"[^"]+"|[^ ]+' a.txt | cat -A
```

Output:

```
foo^Ibar^I"foobar baz qux"$
foo^I"bar foobar baz"^Iqux$
"foo   bar foobar"^Ibaz^Iqux$
```

Comment: As with the code of user _anubhava_, the following file is not processed as expected, probably due to the presence of non-letter characters: `> cat file` `foo_bar_baz foo foo_bar . Name=foo;product="bar baz qux"\nfoo_bar_baz foo foo_bar . Name=foo;product="bar baz qux"\nfoo_bar_baz foo foo_bar . Name=foo;product="bar baz qux"` How would you adjust the code to handle the presence of non-letter characters?

Comment: @MichaelGruenstaeudl Can you add that example to your question? It's hard to follow in comments. Please don't edit the existing example, add the new one (or even open a new question)

Comment: The new example has been appended to the question.

Comment: Good question. I don't know atm.. Will need to investigate that