# Replacing whitespace with single tab unless in double quotes - Part II

Tags: regex, string, bash, awk

The post "[Replacing whitespace with single tab unless in double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870465/replacing-whitespace-with-single-tab-unless-in-double-quotes)" discussed *awk* code with which all whitespaces in a string **outside double quotes** were replaced with single tab characters. Two answers were posted that would correctly conduct said replacement -- **unless** a certain number or combination of non-letter characters is present in the input strings.

Does anyone know what prevents the command from the desired replacement and how to overcome it?

```
> cat file
# foo bar Name product "baz qux"            # Non-letter chars: none
# foo_bar . Name=foo;product="baz qux"      # Non-letter chars: underscore, dot, equal sign, semicolon
# foo-bar +   Name=foo,product="baz   qux"  # Non-letter chars: dash, plus, equal sign, comma, mult. whitespaces
```

Desired output (when piped to `cat -A`):

```
# foo^Ibar^IName^Iproduct^I"baz qux"$
# foo_bar^I.^IName=foo;product="baz qux"$
# foo-bar^I+^IName=foo,product="baz   qux"$
```

Actual output (when piped to `cat -A`):

```
> awk -v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^[:blank:]]+' -v OFS='\t' '{$1=$1} 1' file | cat -A
# foo^Ibar^IName^Iproduct^I"baz qux"$
# foo_bar^I.^IName=foo;product="baz^Iqux"$  # sic!
# foo-bar^I+^IName=foo,product="baz^Iqux"$  # sic!

> awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS='\t' FPAT='"[^"]+"|[^ ]+' file | cat -A
# foo^Ibar^IName^Iproduct^I"baz qux"$
# foo_bar^I.^IName=foo;product="baz^Iqux"$  # sic!
# foo-bar^I+^IName=foo,product="baz^Iqux"$  # sic!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with special characters, change FPAT to:

```
FPAT='("[^"]*"|[^[:blank:]"]+)+'
```

The problem was that fields may contain strings enclosed between quotes **and** other non-space characters outside of the quotes like `Name=foo;product="baz qux"`. The old pattern didn't describe these kind of fields.

Comment: Yes, that seems to have been the issue. The code now conducts the desired replacement. Thank you!